# The avatars on the /teams page should be clickable and link to the user profiles

Tags: feature-request, old-teams

I mean, these ones:

> [image]

Wouldn't it be a *great* idea to make them clickable and link to the corresponding user profiles?

Comment: Would that be an expected action for an user on that page? They are looking for teams, not for users?

Comment: I'd expect it as much as I do for the rankings available on the /users page.

Comment: But the context is in that case already users, right?

Comment: Okay, then the avatars don't make much sense on the /teams page - often it's pretty difficult to guess a user by avatar (except for the first team :), then why do I need to see those images? Solely small pics don't give anything.

Comment: Ok, That is a valid point.

Comment: Small pics entice you to click to the full team page so you can see the avatars, names, and job titles / team affiliations of *all* the team members, not just the ones we preview... :)

Comment: Well, the point of those images is to give an idea of who (and how many) members there are in the team. When I look at the team list, I am more likely to be interested in a team [with those images](http://i.stack.imgur.com/f8nfz.png) than [without](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DAprs.png).